# MS Access: SQL statement "UPDATE" gives vague error 3144 "Syntax error in UPDATE statement"

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I currently am running a form linked to a table where one of the controls displayed in the form is dependent on another another control. Specifically, it is a field called **Machine Excavation** that needs to be the remaining percentage of a user inputted percentage in the field **Hand Excavation**. These fields pertain to a specific record chosen specified from another control in the form called **Excavation Type**. For example if I input 30% into **Hand Excavation** then **Machine Excavation** needs to be 70%. I've created a code that will use a RunSQL method in VBA to store this in the underlying table upon execution of an AfterUpdate event in the **Hand Excavation** control:

```
Private Sub Text_HandExcvPerc_AfterUpdate()

DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE tbl-ExcavationType SET [Machine Excavation] = 1 - [Hand Excavation] WHERE [Excavation Type] = Text_ExcvType.Value;") End Sub
```

**tbl-ExcavationType** is the table linked to the form and **Text_ExcvType.Value** is the textbox control that contains the current record identifier. Can someone comment on the syntax of my DoCmd.RunSQL? I keep getting an error.

Comment: (a) Is `Text_ExcvType.Value` meant to be part of the SQL statement, or did you mean `WHERE [Excavation Type] = " & Text_ExcvType.Value & ";"`? (b) I'm not sure, but `tbl-ExcavationType` may need to be in brackets, i.e. `[tbl-ExcavationType]`.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant for Text_ExcvType.Value but even after using the right syntax given by Harrassed Dad down below, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE [tbl-ExcavationType] SET [Machine Excavation] = " & _
    "1 - [Hand Excavation] WHERE [Excavation Type] = """ & Text_ExcvType.Value & """;")
```

Notice that there are three quotation marks surrounding the text box value. Access uses double quotes instead of single quotes for strings. Because you are entering it in a string, you have to use two double quotes to indicate the single double quote for your string, then another one to break the string to concatenate your value. What the system sees will be effectively this:

```
UPDATE [tbl-ExcavationType] SET [Machine Excavation] = 1 - [Hand Excavation] WHERE [Excavation Type] = "My Data Value";
```

Comment: This did not work. Did you mean to put a set of single quotes in there somewhere? Also, is there another way I can get a value into the table via calculation using values from another field but same specified record? I tried using validation rules but that doesn't automatically populate just restricts inputs.

Comment: Access uses double quotes, not single quotes, so that shouldn't be the problem. Is it giving you the exact same error?

Comment: Yes error3144 something very vague. Is there a way to debug just SQL?

Comment: Just a quick dummy check, make sure that the table name and field names are all spelled correctly. Also, if you used my line break I put in there, make sure you entered that format correctly. You can also try setting your SQL statement as a string and using Debug.Print to make sure it comes out like I showed.

Comment: FWIW - Access accepts either single quotes or double quotes around text values.

Comment: I missed the table name not in brackets. I find it very unusual to name a table with a dash instead of an underscore. This is just one more example of why good naming conventions are important. I updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: Finally worked! Thanks to SandPiper and everyone else!

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues:

1. You need to wrap your table name in brackets because it contains a `-`.
2. You need to enclose your text values in either single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).
3. You need to add the value of `Text_ExcvType.Value` rather than the string `"Text_ExcvType.Value"` into the query.

I have tested that the following works:

```
Private Sub Text_HandExcvPerc_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl-ExcavationType] SET [Machine Excavation] = 1 - [Hand Excavation] WHERE [Excavation Type] = '" & Text_ExcvType.Value "';"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here appears to be a calculated field: ie  [Machine Excavation] is always 1 - [Hand Excavation] so I don't see why you need to store it. That said you need to replace the words "Text_ExcvType.Value" with the actual value in the control called Text_ExcvType and it can't do that while it's inside speech marks. Try

```
dim strsql as string

strsql = "UPDATE tbl-ExcavationType SET [Machine Excavation] = "

strsql = strsql & "1 - [Hand Excavation] WHERE [Excavation Type] = '"

strsql = strsql & Text_ExcvType.Value & "';" 

DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

This allows access to first evaluate Text_ExcvType.Value, put the result into the string and then execute the sql
Doing it this way also allows you to watch the string build in debug to work out where it's going wrong

Comment: First, thanks for the response. I used your code however the same error pops up and the debug highlights the last line the string has already been concatenated. Not sure what else it could be...    Regarding your first question, only queries allow you to input calculations. I can use a validation rule but that doesn't populate the cell automatically.